# Zend Framework - Loading View Helpers from Modules

Tags: zend-framework, configuration, view-helpers

I am putting together a modular application in Zend Framework and am struggling to get module specific View Helpers to load.

My directory structure is like this...

```
application
---configs  
---controllers  
---forms  
---layouts  
---models  
---modules  
------user  
---------controllers  
---------forms  
---------modules  
---------views  
------------filters
------------helpers  
---------------currentUser.php  
------------scripts  
---------Bootstrap.php  
---views  
---Bootstrap.php
```

basically I want to access the view helper that is contained in currentUser.php but when I put

```
<?php echo $this->currentUser(); ?>
```

I get an error stating that the file cannot be found.

What do I need to add to my config file to load these helpers?

My config is something like this...

```
Autoloadernamespaces[] = "Zend_"
Autoloadernamespaces[] = "Default_"
Autoloadernamespaces[] = "User_"

phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"

bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"

resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH    "/controllers"
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"

resources.view[] =
resources.modules[] =
```

Answer (score 4):

I have worked it out...

All I need to do was to add this line to my config file:

```
user.resources.view.helperPath.Zend_View_Helper = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules/user/views/helpers"
```